# How do you move cards between boards on mobile app?

Tags: trello

I am trying to move a card to a different board but do not see a move option on the mobile app.

Where is the 'move' on the Trello mobile application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about a smartphone application, not a web interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can't move cards between boards in the Trello iOS app yet. That's something that I hope to add in the future.

On the Trello mobile web app, you can move a card by tapping the "Move..." button at the bottom of a card and then selecting the board that you want to move it to.

Answer (score 0):

To move a card from one board to another board:

- Open the card you would like to move
- Tap the grey bar at the top of the card that has the board and list name that your card is on
- A window will appear where you can select the board and list you would like to move the card to
- Tap "Move" to move the card

Answer (score -1):

In the Android app,  tap the card to open it,then change the list it belongs to buy tapping the drop down list of available lists and choosing the required one.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - in the Android app you can move a card to a different *list* but not a different *board*.